# collecting MAC adresses from access point configured

Tags: networking

i want to make an access point for my house and i want to collect the mac adresses of the devices connected to the network and save them in a Database, basically what i want to do is having something that tells me everyone that is home, i have a table on my database that has every member of my family, also with a status column called "Status_Id" that needs to be updated when someone connects to the access point and i want to use the mac adresses or Fixed IPs to know who is who and update it.

Note: im planning on doing that on any linux distrib, so if you have any suggestion on how to do it, pleeease let me know.

Comment: hostapd (AP) knows, logs, and can be queried about the clients' MACs in use.

Comment: What's to stop someone from having two devices and leaving one at home?  Or leaving all devices at home to be off-tech for a while?  What do you gain from knowing who is home, and would they mind the prying?

Answer (score 0):

from your distro or http://netfilter.org

You need ulog2 and iptables.  Also ulog-mysql might be a separate package.

```
iptables -A INPUT **some condition if necessary** -j NFLOG
```

You need to add condition here to avoid you database being overloaded with packets.

For dhcp clients I recommend

ulogd.conf

stack=log1:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2bin1:IP2BIN,mac2str1:HWHDR,mysql1:MYSQL
     iptables -I INPUT 1 -m udp -p udp  --dport=67 -j NFLOG --log-prefix "dhcp 67 "
     iptables -I INPUT 2 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j NFLOG

At least rule #2 will slow down the number of logged packs, more refinement probably necessary.  This will be necessary for static IPs.

Then you need to configure /etc/ulogd.conf

I don't have my notes handy, but I can add them later.

You will have to enter a database name, table name, username, password.

You can modify INSERT_FULL_PACKET to insert the relevant records into whatever table you want.

However there is a trick the table name specified in the ulogd.conf.  The ulog program examines what fields are present and only output those fields.
Uncomment the mysql entries.

To Be Continued.....

```
/BASE# Example configuration for ulogd

[global]

user="ulogd"

logfile="/var/log/ulogd/ulogd.log"

loglevel=1

plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_raw2packet_BASE.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_inppkt_NFLOG.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_inpflow_NFCT.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_filter_IFINDEX.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_filter_IP2STR.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_filter_IP2BIN.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_filter_IP2HBIN.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_filter_HWHDR.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_filter_PRINTFLOW.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_filter_MARK.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_output_NACCT.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_output_MYSQL.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_inpflow_NFACCT.so"

stack=log1:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2bin1:IP2BIN,mac2str1:HWHDR,mysql1:MYSQL

[ct1]

[ct2]
hash_enable=0

[log1]
nlgroup=1
group=1
netlink_socket_buffer_size=217088
netlink_socket_buffer_maxsize=1085440

[log2]
group=1 # Group has to be different from the one use in log1
netlink_socket_buffer_size=217088
netlink_socket_buffer_maxsize=10854400

[log3]
group=2 # Group has to be different from the one use in log1/log2
numeric_label=1 # you can label the log info based on the packet verdict

[nuauth1]
socket_path="/tmp/nuauth_ulogd2.sock"

[emu1]
file="/var/log/ulogd/syslogemu.log"
sync=1

[op1]
file="/var/log/ulogd/oprint.log"
sync=1

[gp1]
file="/var/log/ulogd/gprint.log"
sync=1
timestamp=1

[xml1]
directory="/var/log/ulogd/"
sync=1

[json1]
sync=1

[pcap1]
sync=1

[mysql1]
db="database"
host="ip-address"
user="user"
table="table"
pass="password"
procedure="INSERT_PACKET_FULL"
backlog_memcap=20000000
backlog_oneshot_requests=20

[mysql2]
db="database"
host="host"
user="user"
table="table"
pass="password
procedure="INSERT_procedure"

[nacct1]
sync = 1

[mark1]
mark = 1

[acct1]
pollinterval = 2
```

You will need the ulogd file from netfilter.org

to find this file

./doc/mysql-ulogd2.sql

Create the databasename in advanced.

mysql -u root -p databasename < ./doc/mysql-ulogd2.sql

Comment: im going to start with those things, and will be waiting for your answer, thanks bro

Comment: @StanleyGross how far did you get?